# Is it possible to exclude a plugin from Progressive and Conservative cache?

Tags: joomla-4.x

I have a plugin that works fine in that it reads a value from the params of the plugin and then based on the current date/time, replaces it with a new value in the params, however with Progressive or Conservative cache enabled in the Global Configuration the subsequent reads of the value get retrieved from the cache in `administrator/cache/com_config`. Until the cache is cleared my plugin is then retrieving the original value and not the updated value.

Is there a way to exclude a plugin from being cached?

```
$params  = $this->params;
$last    = new DateTime($params->get('sqr_last_update'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the answer by @Sharky suggesting I use the Model from `com_plugins` I have put together a new method that uses the PluginModel to save the change to the `params` and sharing my method  here for others looking to update the plugins params that includes a refresh of the cache.

```
public function updateParams($key, $value)
{
    $this->params->set($key, $value);
    $plugin_model = new PluginModel();
    $plugin_model->save(array('extension_id' => $this->_id, 'params' => $this->params->toString()));
}
```

The property `$this->_id` is not set by default in the `__construct` of `CMSPlugin` class as expected so until that is fixed the following lines of code are required to be executed prior to its use in the last line containing `'extension_id' => $this->_id`.
If you want to use `_id` elsewhere in your plugin I would suggest adding the extra lines towards the beginning of your plugin.

```
// Required to get the extension id until CMSPlugin is updated to provide it. 
$table = new  Extension(Factory::getDbo());
$table->load(array('element' => $this->_name, 'type' => 'plugin', 'folder' => $this->_type));
$this->_id = $table->extension_id;
```

Refer to https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/38094

Comment: Do not use these methods. They don't consider plugin group/folder so you might end up updating the wrong record.

Comment: @Sharky, I have updated the methods to include the _name and _type values. If this still isn't suitable is there any documentation or example you can point me towards of how it should be done?

Comment: I have also raised an issue to address the the fact that the id of the plugin is not available when in the plugin when it should be. This would make the extra processing of the first three line of code in the first sample redundant as the correct id would already be set. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/38094

Comment: I have reworked the answer to be more concise and directly answers my original question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. It's something you would have to handle in the plugin. When an item is edited it's natural to clear the cache. This would be done automatically if you used existing API (i.e. plugin model from `com_plugins`) to update the record instead of manually running database queries. You can also clear the cache manually using the Cache API.

Another option is to manually query the database. There's actually `custom_data` column in `#__extensions` table where you can and should store custom data like this instead of misusing `params` column.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise I was misusing prarams, I will have to read up on how to use that and the com_plugins model to do the update.

Comment: I have looked at the custom_data column and in this usage case the value I am changing via this code also needs to be changed at times by a human through the field input in the plugin. I can't see anyway to change custom_data via the Admin interface so I don't believe I am misusing the params column in this instance.